# Enabling\configuring openssl in mysql on windows

Tags: mysql, ssl

i have tried to configure openssl in mysql .....i did the following steps

1. I have downloaded the openssl.1.0.1 and i have set the path in environment variables.
2. I have created a certificates from Mysql ...Datebase->connect to database in that i have select the SSL Wizards and by clicking next->next->finish .At this stages the keys are generated.
3. After this i have tried to configure in "my.ini" which is present in the MYSQL server ..i have done like this

> [mysqld]
>   ssl-ca=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\certificates{69DA90DA-1065-418B-B3BD-60B467AEF1E4}\ca-cert.pem
>   ssl-cert=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\certificates{69DA90DA-1065-418B-B3BD-60B467AEF1E4}\server-cert.pem
>   ssl-key=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\certificates{69DA90DA-1065-418B-B3BD-60B467AEF1E4}\server-key.pem

4. After this i have restated the mysql. but still it is showing ssl as disabled.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83iPX.png) 
   [image]

5.It is showing the configured path but its not enabling ssl....pls post the solution

Comment: Check this link:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/building-with-ssl-support.html   Near the bottom of this page is some advice that will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: hi thx...i have tried with tht configaration but it uses Cmake to do .i have installed exe and i am trying with the cmake. If i am using cmake command it showing "C:/Windows/System32" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt."..pls help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution ...this disable is because the mysql is not reading that file... i have changed the pathname....ssl-ca="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\cert\ca-cert.pem" ssl-cert="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\cert\server-cert.pem" ssl-key="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\cert\server-key.pem"...thax all for the support..